# Using diffrent parts of an image for links with css or html

Tags: html, css

How can I use the following image as a image map :

http://www.mesuva.com.au/files/cache/e5240d6d59c3351f7a0ac68dec836d95_f253.png

I want to use parts of the image for the following links :

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/foo"><img src="/twitter.png"></a>
<a href="http://facebook.com/foo"><img src="/fb.png"></a>

<a href="http://plus.google.com/foo"><img src="/fb.png"></a>
```

How Is this possible with CSS or HTML?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you referring to an [image map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map) or an [image sprite](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Images/Implementing_image_sprites_in_CSS)?

Comment: I want to create an image map.

Comment: you can use as a `background-image` for `a` tag with `background-position`

Answer (score 1):

Two possible solutions come to mind.

One. Create four link elements in the arrangement of your choice, and then set their background using http://www.mesuva.com.au/files/cache/e5240d6d59c3351f7a0ac68dec836d95_f253.png as a sprite.

Here's some good info on that: https://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/

---

Two. Float four link elements within a parent, with the parent element's background set to the given image. Like so:

html:

```
<div class="parent">
    <a class="child">Twitter</a>
    <a class="child">etc</a>
    <a class="child">etc</a>
    <a class="child">etc</a>
</div>
```

css:

```
.parent {
    background-image: url(http://www.mesuva.com.au/files/cache/e5240d6d59c3351f7a0ac68dec836d95_f253.png)
    height: x;
    width: y;
}
.child {
    display: block;
    width: x/4;
    height: y/4;
    float: left;
}
```

Where you determine what x & y are. Based on your needs.

**These are purposely general and flexible solutions.**

---

**EDIT:**
Sorry, just realized, you wanted an image map... BAM!! http://imagemap-generator.dariodomi.de/

Comment: Oh... hmm didn't know an image map was an actual thing. Sorry!

Comment: I tried your css solution, but the image is not getting displayed.

Answer (score 1):

[Here's how to create an image map](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp).

You'll need to know the coordinates of the virtual rectangle; [each number is a corner](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_area_coords.asp) in pixels relative to the image.

Comment: Thank you for the link. I have already tried it ,but I dont understand how to use coords. Is there any way to do it with CSS?

Comment: Not just with CSS, no. You need to assign properties to the HTML map element; they aren't styles.  Again coords are just the position of points.  The top left corner of your image is 0, 0.  If the image width was 560 pixels, then the top right corner is 560, 0.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `<map>` *HTML* tag with the `<area>` tags.

```
<map name = "mymap">
    <area shape = "rect"   coords = "x,y,w,h" href = "http...">
    <area shape = "circle" coords = "x,y,r"   href = "http...">
</map>

<img src = "myimage" usemap = "#mymap">
```

For more look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/area).

Also, you can try this [website](https://www.image-maps.com/) will help you make the areas.